# How to sum up the numbers in sequence only when the time interval between them is very small

Tags: r

this is very simple thing I am trying to do: I want to add the numbers consequently if their times are close to each other, if not I would like to keep the number. The time limit which dictates how close they are together I set up manually (here it is 0.03). I want then store these numbers for further manipulation. I want to run this across, and if the 1.23 and 1.24 fit the criteria I want to add 1+2, but then I want to compare 1.24 and 1.25 and they satisfy the condition too so then 1+2+1, and so on. Once they are no longer close I would store this number and move on. The output vector would then be smaller in size. This is the output I want

output = (1 + 2 + 1 + 5, 3 + 4, 11 + 13, 25 + 1, 11, 7)

output = (9, 7, 24, 26, 11, 7)

This is what I have so far:

```
v1 <- c(1,2,1,5,3,4,11,13, 25, 1)
t1 <- c(1.23, 1.24, 1.25, 1.28, 2.28, 2.29, 2.90, 2.91, 3.11, 3.12)

i<-1
j<-2
sums <- NULL
tot <- NULL
while (j <= length(v1))
{
  if (t1[j] - t1[i] < 0.03)
    {
    sums[i] <- v1[i] + v1[j]
    }
  if (t1[j] - t1[i] > 0.03)
  {
    tot[i] <- v1[i]
  } 
  i = i + 1
  j = j + 1
}
```

Comment: With a threshold at 0.02, 5 should not be added to 1+2+1 in your output ?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I was playing around with the limits before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work :

```
v1 <- c(1,2,1,5,3,4,11,13, 25, 1)
t1 <- c(1.23, 1.24, 1.25, 1.28, 2.28, 2.29, 2.90, 2.91, 3.11, 3.12)
threshold <- 0.02

fac <- c(1, cumsum(diff(t1) > threshold) + 1)
as.vector(tapply(v1, fac, sum))
```

Which gives :

```
# [1]  4  5  7 24 26
```

If you want to compute things on this output, as suggested in your comment, you should store it in a data frame. For example :

```
df <- data.frame(v1, t1)
df$fac <- c(1, cumsum(diff(t1) > threshold) + 1)
library(plyr)
df2 <- ddply(df, "fac", summarize, v1=sum(v1), t1=min(t1))
df2$time <- cut(df2$t1, breaks=1:4)
```

Which would give :

```
R> df2
  fac v1   t1  time
1   1  4 1.23 (1,2]
2   2  5 1.28 (1,2]
3   3  7 2.28 (2,3]
4   4 24 2.90 (2,3]
5   5 26 3.11 (3,4]
```

Comment: I know my question is quite simple, but I'm really grateful for your help!!! Merci! What reading material would you recommend as I am just starting with R?

Comment: Thank you juba! another question (I asked the same to Roland): How can I  further check if the other numbers in sequence v1[i + 1], v[i+2] and so on are close to the original v[i]. And if they are at similar limit as that for v[i] and v[i+1] I want to sum them up too and store this number as the true value in the new "as.vector"?

Comment: @pops There's plenty of reading material, it depends on your language, your experience in programming, etc. You can start with the R manuals, or with one of the documents listed in the contrib documentation : http://cran.r-project.org/other-docs.html

Comment: @pops For your second comment, you should edit your question describing precisely what you want to achieve...

Comment: 1) Based on the threshold (0.03) cuts I want to store the time at which the counting began: times = (1.23, 2.28, 2.90, 3.11)  
desired output = (9, 7, 24, 26) so I can plot the clipped volume and the corresponding times.

2) Then I want to cut the intervals into 1 second segments from 1:2, 2:3, 3:4 and so on and record them so I can plot the aggregated time and the values too

desired output = (9, 31, 26...) 
desired times = (1:2, 2:3, 3:4...)

Comment: Just edited my comment. But in the future, don't ask another question in a comment to an answer. Best is to ask everything in your initial question. If you didn't, edit your partial question or create a new one.

Comment: I will write everything I have a problem with next time around, thank you juba!

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using clustering:

```
#Cluster according to distance
hr <- hclust(dist(t1))

#plot a dendrogram
plot(hr)

# cut at desired distance
hc <- cutree(hr, h=0.02)

#highlight in dendrogram
rect.hclust(hr, h=0.02)
```

[image]

```
aggregate(v1, list(hc), sum)
#   Group.1  x
# 1       1  3
# 2       2  1
# 3       3  5
# 4       4  7
# 5       5 24
# 6       6 26
```

Note that this does not give exactly the result as the recursive approach outlined in your question, but it seems more sensible this way. You could control the clustering using different cutoff values.

```
#Use 0.03 for cutoff instead:
aggregate(v1, list(cutree(hr, h=0.03)), sum)
#   Group.1  x
# 1       1  4
# 2       2  5
# 3       3  7
# 4       4 24
# 5       5 26
```

Comment: Thank you Roland! another question: How can I use this to further check if the other numbers in sequence v1[i + 1], v[i+2] and so on are close to the original v[i]. And if they are at similar limit as that for v[i] and v[i+1] I want to add them to sum them up too and store this number as the true value?